# PHP How to validate URL with id ungiven parameter?

Tags: php, mysql, validation, url

I have a website where I can show a single post with `view_post.php?id=1` but when I try to show a post with for example `view_post.php?id= or view_post.php?id` it shows nothing.
Then I tried to Log the Database Query like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id='$postIdFromUrl'";
$stmt = $db->query($query);
                        
if (!$stmt) {
    $_SESSION["test"] = $stmt;
    redirect_to("Blog.php");
}
```

It doesnt show anything as the query is valid.
So my question is how to validate that. I tried a lot of things with e.g. URL Validation... nothing worked.

I would be very happy if someone could send me a code that can check for that.
Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: Check if the query yields a result. And before the query check if the `$id` submitted has a value.

Comment: A query that returns 0 rows isn't necessarily invalid. You should check the number of rows returned.

Answer (score 0):

just check if id exists or its empty before u do anything

```
if (isset($_GET['id']) && !empty($_GET['id'])) {
    //do your original code
} else {
    redirect_to("Blog.php");
}
```